# htaccess remove only '?=' sign from URL with query string

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

i have url like :

http://www.domain.com/16-7-2013/PHP_NEW/registration.php?id=56

and i want to display it like:

http://www.domain.com/16-7-2013/PHP_NEW/registration/56

can anybody please help me to get out of this stuff.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is variable in this URL? Only the ID? Or the date and `PHP_NEW` too?

Comment: sorry guys, i have edited my question , can you please answer regarding that..?

Comment: Can you answer my question? So I can provide you with a accurate solution.

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER ID is variable, that i have passed, and rest of all are directory name

Comment: But are there other directories where this rule also should work? If yes, how are they named.

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER sorry, it is working, but i can't disclose their names.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule registration/id/(\d+)$ /16-7-2013/PHP_NEW/registration.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys,

it is resolved by this.

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^registration/(.*)$ ./registration.php?id=$1
```

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

you have to write rewrite rule some thing like this

```
^16-7-2013/PHP_NEW/registration/id/(.*)$ registration.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```